# Is it possible to use warlock's Hideous Blow in barbarian's rage?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, class

According to the Complete Arcane book, warlock invocations are *not* spells.
Barbarian rage description in PHB1 says:

> While raging, a barbarian cannot use any Charisma-, Dexterity-, or Intelligence-based skills (except for Balance, Escape Artist, Intimidate, and Ride), the Concentration skill, or any abilities that require patience or concentration, nor can he cast spells or activate magic items that require a command word, a spell trigger (such as a wand), or spell completion (such as a scroll) to function. He can use any feat he has except Combat Expertise, item creation feats, and metamagic feats.

So, if invocations are not spells - can I use it in rage?
If they are spells can I just multiclass into Rage Mage from Complete Warrior handbook? In the other words invocations are arcane spells or not?

Comment: I made a small edit to help readability, but I don't speak 3.5 so do please double check that I didn't muck anything subtle up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Typically *no* as warlock invocations are usually spell-like abilities and, as such, require concentration

Warlock invocations like the least invocation ***hideous blow*** (*Complete Arcane* 134) are typically [spell-like abilities](http://dndsrd.net/actionsInCombat.html#using-spell-like-abilities) (*CAr* 7), and "[u]sing a spell-like ability… works like casting a spell in that it requires concentration…" (*Player's Handbook* 142).

Because the extraordinary ability [rage](http://dndsrd.net/barbarian.html#barbarian-rage) says that the rager "cannot use… any abilities that require… concentration" (*PH* 25), the typical creature can't employ any spell-like abilities while raging.

Further, *Complete Arcane* says, "A warlock cannot qualify for prestige classes with spellcasting level requirements, as he never actually learns to cast spells" (18). The prestige class rage mage has as an entry requirement *Special: Able to cast 2nd-level arcane spells* (72), meaning that a typical single-classed warlock can't meet that requirement.

Even were the warlock to meet this requirement of the prestige class rage mage by, for instance, multiclassing, the rage magic extraordinary ability **spell rage** only allows the rage mage to cast spells while in a spell rage, not mentioning the rage mage being able to use spell-like abilities.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But if i take feat "Supernatural Transformation" from Savage Species, can i applicate it on Hideous Blow? In the other words, are warlock's invocations is innate abilities?

Comment: @Suicide In response to a question a whole lot like that the *FAQ* says, "The warlock’s spell-like abilities are learned (from class levels), not innate (that is, part of his racial traits)" (28). I don't know this ruling's provenance, and some folks (like me) [take issue with the *FAQ*.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60044/8610)  In other words, ask the DM (or ask a new question and see what happens).